# what is benefit of defining db pool in tomcat vs in spring configuring file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

what is benefit of defining db pool in tomcat vs  in spring configuring file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DBCPosPool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="30" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               testOnBorrow="true"
               username="xxx" password="xxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://abcd.com/test2?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

Comment: This db pool is available to all your web apps running in tomcat.

Comment: Defining it in Tomcat makes it managed by the container itself, rather by the application (Spring).

Answer (score 6):

I can think of 3 benefits.

1. Your datasource can be reused by other web applications
2. Your datasource can be administered externally, independant from the web application. You never want to re-deploy code if the datasource changes. In big organisations the developer is usually not the person who administers the datasources and stuff.
3. Environment specific details. It's possible that you're working in a DTAP environments or something similar. The datasource can be different depending on your environment (development, production, ...). You don't want to maintain seperate Spring configuration files just for the sake of the data connection.

Answer (score 1):

Defining pool in tomcat allows you to reuse this definition in others, non spring apps. Defining it in spring level helps you to deploy yor app including other containers.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is packaged to a war file, defining resources in an application server allows you to modify the resources without rebuilding the application. All you need is to restart the application server. This is useful when deploying the same application on different environments (dev, test, prod etc).